# Serial1/2/3 on Arduino Mega not working as expected

Tags: arduino, atmega

I want to connect a Bluetooth HC-05 module to Arduino Mega using serial pins other than `Serial` (tx0, rx0), because I want to use `Serial` for debugging.

Now the problem is, that when I connect the module to the `Serial` (tx0, rx0), it works fine, but when I connect it to other serials (`Serial1/2/3`), it returns semi-random values.

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial2.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial2.available ()) {
    Serial.println(Serial2.read());
  }
}
```

I entered the input:

```
a
s
d
f
g
```

And the output I get is:

```
0
64
0
0
6
```

I have tried putting `if{}` instead of `while{}`, but it still outputs the same values. What am I doing wrong here?